# passing $_POST values through PHP pagination

Tags: php, session, post, pagination

so I'm having some issues with a pagination script I have been building The pagination works fine however when i load a new page using the next button, my search term `$search_term = "%" . $_POST['searchBar'] . "%";` is lost. is there any way to avoid this? or set the search term as a set value?

the url for the next page is like so - `http://examplewebsite.com/user/Courses/SearchResultsPage.php?pn=2`

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

The rest of the pagination script is below;

```
    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password','db');
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
    {
        die('Database connection failed');
    }
//$m->set_charset('utf8');
//here are my main changes
//turn errors on to develop, back off when you go live
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$search_term = "%" . $_POST['searchBar'] . "%";
$search_param = $_SESSION['$search_term']=$search_term;
$stmt =$mysqli->prepare("SELECT title, summary, id FROM course WHERE title
LIKE ?");   
$stmt->bind_param("s", $search_param); //learn this
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

//This gets the number of rows in a query result
$rows = $result->num_rows;

//number of results per page
$rows_per_page = 10;

//shows last page
$last_page = ceil($rows/$rows_per_page);
if($last_page < 1){
$last_page = 1;
}

if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
    $page_number = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
} else {
$page_number = 1;
}

//makes sure page number is between limits of $page_number
if($page_number < 1){
    $page_number = 1;
} else if($page_number > $last_page){
    $page_number = $last_page;
}

// sets the value of items to view
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($page_number -1) * $rows_per_page .',' .$rows_per_page;

//displays to the user the total number of results and the page numbers
$total_number_of_results = "Search Results (<b>$rows</b>)";
$page_user_is_on = "Page <b>$page_number</b> of <b>$last_page</b>";

//query again only grabbing the set number of rows depending on page number
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT title, summary, id FROM course WHERE title LIKE ? ".$limit);   
$stmt->bind_param("s", $search_param);
$stmt->execute(); 
$result = $stmt->get_result();


$list = ''; 
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$title = $row['title'];
$id = $row['id'];
//I'm assuming you want each link to be different here...
$list.='<p><a href="Selectedcourse.php?id='.$id.'">' . $title . '</a></p>';
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);

//set up pagination
$pagination_controls = '';
if($last_page != 1){
    if($page_number > 1){
        $previous = $page_number - 1;
        $pagination_controls .='<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
        for($i = $page_number - 4; $i < $page_number; $i++)
        {
            if($i > 0){
            $pagination_controls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
        }
    }
}
$pagination_controls.=''.$page_number.' &nbsp; ';

//clickable links to the left
for($i = $page_number+1; $i <= $last_page; $i++)
    {
        $pagination_controls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
        if($i >= $page_number+4){
            break;
        }
    }
    if($page_number != $last_page){
        $next = $page_number + 1;
        $pagination_controls.='&nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a>';
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='courses.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
<h1>Search Results for - <?= $search_param ?></h1>
</div>
<div>
<h3> <?php echo $page_user_is_on ?> </h3>
<p><?php echo $list; ?></p>
<p><?php /* echo $search_result['summary']; //Where was this coming from? */?> </p>
</div>
<div id="pagination_controls"><?php echo $pagination_controls; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the full page code

Comment: @Mihai thats the full document there now

Comment: Question is, why are you using sessions? Your previous question did not use them and works.

Comment: @Fred-ii- how do you mean it works fine?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case with your new question here then. You're losing your search term because you're also not checking if the session array is set/not empty, while maybe adding another parameter to the search url.

Comment: Then here `$_SESSION['$search_term']` get rid of that `$` sign. `$_SESSION['search_term']`. Edit: I hadn't seen Mihai's edit when I posted this comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you click next, the page refreshes and since you dont use

```
<?php
session_start();
....
```

Replace these 2 lines

```
$search_term = "%" . $_POST['searchBar'] . "%";
$search_param = $_SESSION['$search_term']=$search_term;
```

with:

```
if(isset( $_POST['searchBar'])){
   $search_term = "%" . $_POST['searchBar'] . "%";
   $search_param = $_SESSION['search'] = $search_term ;
}
else {
   $search_param = $_SESSION['search'];
}
```

at the top,`$_SESSION['$search_term']` is lost

Also add an isset check for your POST

EDIT

I think your problem is that $search_term is set only on load then on the next page it is NULL and session is also set to NULL.

Comment: ok so how do i encorporate that into my code? is it as simple as putting `session_start();` on the line above?

Comment: i have added this in and it still throws the error `Notice: Undefined index: searchBar in SearchResultsPage.php on line 15` and looses the `$search_param` value

Comment: grand the erros have gone but the search term is still coming back blank?

Comment: yes it does work before clicking next it is only once next is clicked or one of the other pages is selected. this is when the `$search_term` is lost

Comment: @bdg Edit your question with the url generated for next page button

Comment: Thanks, Thats it working now. Thank you for your help!